# LINQ2XML approach to generalize iteration through xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to parse some xml files (using LINQ) to use that data to store in DB. Following is the format for one of the service, and there are dozens of them more, each with different node patterns and structure.

Is there a way to generalize this approach, so that I can iterate all these services through a single method/lines of code? without being bothered by how the childNodes are arranged ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<deviceState>
<id>203948-2908093-203984902-29348020-290lk</id>
<device>Mirron</device>
<variable>
      <id>Plug - Meter.VI</id>
      <text>
         <textValue>
            <value>0.000000</value>
         </textValue>
      </text>
   </variable>

 <variable>
      <id>AEB</id>
      <text>
         <textStr>-</textStr>
      </text>
   </variable>
 <variable>
      <id>DESCRIPTION</id>
      <text>
         <textStr />
      </text>
   </variable>
 <variable>
      <id>VDTTM</id>
      <text>
         <textDate>
            <date>01042016103658</date>
         </textDate>
      </text>
   </variable>
 <variable>
      <id>STATUS</id>
      <text>
         <textValue>
            <value>1.000000</value>
         </textValue>
      </text>
   </variable>
</deviceState>
```

I want to achieve a functionality, where I can access values of every variable id by specifying a search filter and then access it's value directly, without being bothered by following meaningless tags.

```
<text><textValue> or <text><textDate> or <text><textStr/> or <text>
<textvalue><value>
```

something like, lets say `new devices {a.id=node("id"), a.value=node("valu")}`.

Currently I am using following code which does the trick but its not efficient, neither in speed, nor in manageability.

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(_back);
            string back = "";
                string xvalue, yvalue;
                foreach (XElement xe in x.Descendants().Take(1))
                {

                    var s = xe.Value.IndexOf("Plug - Meter.VI");
                    var val = xe.Value.Substring(s, 25);
                     back= val.Substring(val.LastIndexOf("I")+1, 10);
                break;
                }
```

Any guidance will be highly appreciated. Thanks

---

Based on Monty's feedback, this is what I am using.

```
public protoDCM_CornerL08UMS_View()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

             StartingMeter();

         }


  private async void StartingMeter()
         {
             string val="0";
             max = min = 0;

             await Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 do
                 {
                     UpdateUI(val,max,min);
                     val = fetchData();
                     Double temp =0;
                     if (Double.TryParse(val,out temp))
                     {
                         if(min==0&&max==0)
                         {
                             min = max = temp;
                         }
                         if(temp>max)
                         {
                             max = temp;
                         }
                         if(temp<min)
                         {
                             min = temp;
                         }

                     }
                     val = temp.ToString();
                 }
                 while (true);

             });
         }

  private void UpdateUI(string value, Double _max , Double _min)
         {
             var timeNow = DateTime.Now;

             if ((DateTime.Now - previousTime).Milliseconds <= 50) return;

             synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
             {
                 lblInstant.Text= (string)o;
             }), value);

             synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
             {
                 lblMax.Text = (string)o;
             }), _max.ToString());



             synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
             {
                 lblMin.Text = (string)o;
             }), _min.ToString());

             previousTime = timeNow;
         }

  public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
                 {
                     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                     StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                     writer.Write(s);
                     writer.Flush();
                     stream.Position = 0;
                     return stream;
                 }

         private string fetchData()
         {


                 String _back = HttpGet("http://xxx.xxx.xxx"+Global.Node.Current.Device.Address+"/services/devices/deviceState.xml?id=D83AE139-E0C9-4B15-B2A9-6E0B57B28ED1?type=ALL");
             //_back = FormatXML(Response);
             try
             {
                 DeviceState deserializedXML = new DeviceState();

                 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DeviceState));
                 using (Stream stream = GenerateStreamFromString(_back))
                 {
                     deserializedXML = (DeviceState)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

                     var x = (from z in deserializedXML.Variable
                              where z.Id == "Plug - Meter.VI"
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = z.Id,
                                value= (z.Text.TextDate == null?
                               (z.Text.TextStr == null
                               ? (z.Text.TextValue == null
                               ? "No Text Value!" : z.Text.TextValue.Value.ToString())  : z.Text.TextStr.ToString()) : z.Text.TextDate.Date.ToString())  }).FirstOrDefault();

                     return x.value;

                 } 
             }
             catch (Exception w)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(w.ToString());
                 return "0.0";
             }
         }

   public static string HttpGet(string URI)
         {
             try
             {

                 System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
                 req.Method = "GET";
                System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                 System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                 return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
             }
             catch (Exception sl)
             {
return sl.ToString();
             }
         }
```

Comment: What database are you using?  You may want to load xml file directly into database instead of parsing in c#.

Comment: I am using MS SQLSERVER but, before doing that I have to process this information.

Comment: How large is the xml?   For Large XML using XmlTextReader is better.  You don't have to read entire file at one time.  Is there a reason you are using the Parse() method instead of Load()?

Comment: large is not a concern, instead frequency and variance is needed to be handled. beside that, I am not using xml files, these are simple Get requests on xmlservice which needed to be handled for various purposes including GUI update, data streaming without saving, calculations etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

Usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Classes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "textValue")]
public class TextValue
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "text")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "textValue")]
    public TextValue TextValue { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "textStr")]
    public string TextStr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "textDate")]
    public TextDate TextDate { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "variable")]
public class Variable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "text")]
    public Text Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "textDate")]
public class TextDate
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "deviceState")]
public class DeviceState
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "device")]
    public string Device { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "variable")]
    public List<Variable> Variable { get; set; }
}
```

code

```
        try
        {
            DeviceState deserializedXML = new DeviceState();
            // Deserialize to object
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DeviceState));
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"xml.xml"))
            {
                deserializedXML = (DeviceState)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

                // Now get all your IDs
                List<string> IDs = (from xml in deserializedXML.Variable select xml.Id).ToList();
            } // Put a break-point here, then mouse-over IDs and you will see all your IDs... deserializedXML contains the entire object if you want anythin else ....
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

I read your XML from a file (xml.xml) that is in the application *.exe folder, you will need to adapt this solution depending on your specific requirements....

Is this what you need?....

```
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer DeserializerPlaces = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DeviceState));

            string html = string.Empty;
            string url = @"https://<Your URL>";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            //request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                DeviceState dezerializedXML = (DeviceState)DeserializerPlaces.Deserialize(reader);
                //html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(html);

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

You would call that every 5 seconds and update your UI (from dezerializedXML properties)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I would be getting 1 of this file ( and i have many) every 5 seconds (HTTP GET). do you think it wouldn't impact the speed of solution? it's part of HMI dashboard and i will be updating UI based on these variables.

Comment: I posted an update to this post using your suggestions. Its pretty much doing everything I needed. Hopefully it lasts for the rest of xml services as well :) Thanks .
I will test you updated answer and report back